# How do I turn off the keyboard backlight on my Lenovo Y70?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, backlight

I'd like to turn off the keyboard backlight on my new Lenovo Y70 laptop.

Is there a built-in way of doing this?
Or is there a way to physically disconnect the backlighting from the power supply, if I opened it up myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key combination `Fn + Space` will adjust the keyboard backlight between off, dim, and bright modes.

Comment: worked for my t550 as well. Seems like universal combination for lenovo.

Answer (score 1):

on my Lenovo T440 it's `Fn` + `Space`, I'd suspect the Y70 has the same shortcut